# Android Studio warning "Missing permissions required by AudioRecord.AudioRecord: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"

Tags: android-studio, android-studio-chipmunk

The following code works fine:

```
if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(_activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
   _ar = new AudioRecord(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC, iAudioSampleRate, AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO, AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT, N * 10);
}
```

The Android Studio always gives the warning "Missing permissions required by AudioRecord.AudioRecord: android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"
[image]

The AndroidManifest.xml already has the following:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

If I click "Add Permission RECORD_AUDIO", Android adds another line of permission, so the AndroidManifest has two:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
```

The warning still does not go away. Could anyone shed some light on this?

This is a library project.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I'm having the same issue with CameraX (1.2.0-alpha01) and decided to suppress the warning with `@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")` and still check/request my permissions at runtime, similar to this [example](https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXVideo/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/camerax/video/fragments) by Google.